# Flash to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, audio

I have just finished stage 1 for this site: http://union42.com/

It currently uses flash for the bar scene on the first page. What I would like to do is recreate this bar scene using javascript and then have it fallback to the flash version. Currently it uses flash and then has a flat image as a fallback.

What I would like to know is how to position the roll overs in the bar scene to trigger the sounds, is that possible? I know the scrolling from side to side is fairly straight forward.

Comment: Using HTML5 and `audio`, yes.

Comment: How would you position the hit areas for the sound?

Comment: Make them elements (quite irrelevant what type) and then bind to them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. could you give me an example of the code I should use for this?

Comment: Plenty of examples on Google - don't be lazy! ;)